How to load/play an AAC audio discarding bytes from start of file (junk bytes header) using AVAudioFile + AVAudioPlayerNode (swift)
I have a large file containing several aac audios, in sort of "blocks" (each audio separated by some junk bytes). I need to load each file separately (using start/offset bytes to pick each audio file).
I currently use AVAudioFile + AVAudioPlayerNode, but with this I can only load a pure aac audio file using url/path (I cannot use start/offset to read several audios within a single large file)

You could read the aac data into AVAudioCompressedBuffers (you'll probably need the AudioFileStream API to get the packet offsets), decompress them to AVAudioPCMBuffers using AVAudioConverter and schedule the PCM buffers with your original AVAudioPlayerNode.
Or you could just copy the aac chunks out into individual .aac files and play those with your original AVAudioFile + AVAudioPlayerNode.
